@ConfigurationProperties and duplicated prefix
Since @ConfigurationProperties does not allow duplicated prefix. How to make the follow case to work? The following code will throw error as duplicated prefix is not allowed
abstract class Base {
    var key: String

    abstract fun execute()
}



@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
fun getA() : Base {
    return object : Base {
        override fun execute() {
           // do something
        }
    }
}
 
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
fun getB() : Base {
    return object : Base {
        override fun execute() {
           // do something else
        }
    }
}

properties.yml
test:
   key: value


Note the Base class is in a lib so not possible to change

First, you should create a @ConfigurationProperties class that defines all of the properties that you want to be able to configure on an instance of Base. Here's an example with properties one and two:
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties("test")
public class TestProperties {
    
    private String one;
    
    private String two;

    public String getOne() {
        return one;
    }

    public void setOne(String one) {
        this.one = one;
    }

    public String getTwo() {
        return two;
    }

    public void setTwo(String two) {
        this.two = two;
    }

}

You then enable this properties class using @EnableConfigurationProperties and use the instance of it that Spring Boot creates to configure your sub-classes of Base:
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TestProperties.class)
class ExampleConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    Base getA(TestProperties properties) {
        Base a = new Base() {
            void execute() {
                
            }
        };
        configure(a, properties);
        return a;
    }
    
    @Bean
    Base getB(TestProperties properties) {
        Base b = new Base() {
            void execute() {
                
            }
        };
        configure(b, properties);
        return b;
    }
    
    private void configure(Base base, TestProperties properties) {
        base.setOne(properties.getOne());
        base.setTwo(properties.getTwo());
    }

}

